# Support for "OAuth 2.0 for TV and Limited-Input Device Applications" .Net Client

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

I can't find any examples for the "OAuth 2.0 for TV and Limited-Input Device Applications" auth flow using the "Drive API Client Library for .NET". Isn't it supported? Does anyone know if someone has developed this in another api?
Will Google develop support for this in the .net client api?

OAuth 2.0 for TV and Limited-Input Device Applications:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices

Drive API Client Library for .NET:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/drive/v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the API source from GIT and found that the solution was acutally already implemeted. Turned out I had to write this:

```
credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(authorizationCodeFlowInitializer,Scopes,"user",CancellationToken.None,null, new PromptCodeReceiver());
```

instead of this:

```
credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(authorizationCodeFlowInitializer,Scopes,"user",CancellationToken.None);
```

Case closed!